# ElasticSearch 5.0 + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Installed a fresh ElasticSearch 5.0 today and changed my Rails configuration to point to ES 5.

My `elasticsearch.rb` configuration file looks like:

```
require "faraday"
require "typhoeus/adapters/faraday"

config = {
  host: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.yyyy:9200/",
  transport_options: {
    request: { timeout: 5 }
  },
}

if File.exists?("config/elasticsearch.yml")
  config.merge!(YAML.load_file("config/elasticsearch.yml").symbolize_keys)
end
```

I have the following related gems installed on the application:

```
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
gem 'elasticsearch-persistence', require: 'elasticsearch/persistence/model'
```

When I go to start my application, I receive the message:

`[400] No handler found for uri [//****] and method [DELETE] (Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest)`

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

I looked around for a bit and it looks like ElasticSearch 5.0 has a new API for deleting, but I'm not sure if this is the root cause of my issues:

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/docs-delete-by-query.html

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According this [discussion](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/issues/316) The problem is the `proxy_options` configuration. Just ignore the `transport_options`. If you change the configuration as following it should work.

```
config = {
  hosts: default_host,
  adapter: :typhoeus
}
```